# How to generate JPA mapping file from the JPA annotated entity classes?

Tags: java, maven-2, jpa, maven-plugin, openjpa

I am using openjpa runtime of JPA specification.
At development time I am using annotations to configure jpa entities.
At Integration, Pre-Production and and Production environment, I am using orm mapping files to configure entities. Please suggest a tool which can generate mapping files from jpa annotations, so that these mapping files can be manually edited for different environment.
If there is already a opensource maven-plugin; will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know OpenJPA so there is maybe a better way to do this but one option would be to first generate the XML schema file from annotated entities using the *[Schema Tool](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.2/apache-openjpa-1.0.2/docs/manual/ref_guide_schema_schematool.html)* and then the `orm.xml` file from the `schema.xml` using the *[Reverse Mapping Tool](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.2/apache-openjpa-1.0.2/docs/manual/ref_guide_pc_reverse.html)*. Actually, this process is discussed in [this thread](http://n2.nabble.com/Could-not-locate-metadata-orm-xml-td210107.html).

I've checked the [OpenJPA Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/openjpa-maven-plugin/) but it doesn't seem to support the Reverse Mapping part (it only has a [openjpa:schema](http://mojo.codehaus.org/openjpa-maven-plugin/schema-mojo.html) goal that allows to *Create a file which contains the schema mapping XML*, the first required operation, but nothing for the second part). Extending the plugin to add the missing openjpa:reverse-mapping goal would thus require some development but it shouldn't be an hard task.

There is another option though.  OpenJPA provides the following Ant tasks for both operations:

- [`org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.ant.ReverseMappingToolTask`](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.2/apache-openjpa-1.0.2/docs/manual/ref_guide_integration.html#ref_guide_integration_revmappingtool)
- [`org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.ant.SchemaToolTask`](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.2/apache-openjpa-1.0.2/docs/manual/ref_guide_integration.html#ref_guide_integration_schematool)

So it should be possible to call them from Maven using the [Maven AntRun Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/). Check the documentation for more details on how to use them.

Comment: Thanks Pascal, I will try this proposed solution.